# Ad Hoc entry to managed meta data text box

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, term-store

When dealing with managed meta data column the only way you can add a new term to your term set is to click the Add New Item from the prompted here:

[image]

Now, is it possible to be able to instead bypass the above way and add them directly from the text box like so:

[image]

And once saved it will add the new terms to the term set as well as show in the column.

If this is possible and you are knowledgeable about what I am trying to accomplish can you point me in the right direction of API or someone who has accomplished this.

Update 1:

I was able to find a possible answer for my question on the MSDN network. It looks like I will using REST API.

Here is the link of what I will be using:

http://www.vrdmn.com/2012/12/working-with-taxonomy-and-javascript-in.html

I will update again to what I find.

Update 2:

Well i'm completely stumped. If someone could help me or get me started I would appreciate it.

Comment: You can definitely create a term from a textbox with some custom code but where do you want to use it? Normally if you would like to update the terms you go to the Termstore management. But if you would like to add some new terms while creating list items then the way that you described in your question will be used. But if you would like to create a term from some textbox where do you use it? Do you want to create a web part and place the functionality in it?

Comment: User adaption is the priority with this solution. To be able to quickly add a new term by just adding it from the managed meta data text box would make the flow of adding new clients easier and smooth.

As for your question I am unsure the correct way to go about this.